# YouTube BigQuery channel transfer doesn't appear to be importing all the videos

Tags: google-bigquery

I used the BigQuery YouTube Channel Transfer, however, it seems to skip importing days, videos, or giving the wrong view count. I'm finding these issues only for August/September 2020. The transfer log indicates that it was successful and I have tried to re-backfill these dates. Has anyone encountered this before?

For example:

BQ Transfer will show:

video_id: 12345,
date: 2020-09-01,
views: 1

The YouTube Studio for Analytics will show:

video_id: 12345,
date:2020-09-01,
views: 76

Comment: Hi @melissa did you manage to solve the issue? I am facing the same issue and would love to know how to make it work.

Comment: Sadly, I have not had this resolved. I submitted a ticket a few weeks ago and have not had any answers. My workaround was to use a targeted query for those days, but we only have approximately 1K videos so it wasn't a huge deal.